# Perl - Sort multidimensional array

Tags: perl

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
do {
  my $a = {
    computers => [
      {
        report_date_epoch => 1591107993595,
        serial_number => "C02YK1TAFVCF",
        username => "fake1\@example.com",
      },
      {
        report_date_epoch => 1626877069476,
        serial_number => "C03XF8AWJG5H",
        username => "fake2\@example.com",
      },
...
```

And I'd like to sort it by the epoch number into a new variable without the `computers` array.

Comment: "_without the `computers` array._"  -- i don't understand? Can you show your  expected output?

Comment: Don't use `$a` and `$b`; they are somewhat special and using them outside `sort`'s compare function can cause issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of hashrefs in the arrayref for `computer` key sorted

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $v = { 
    computers => [
        {
            report_date_epoch => 1591107993595,
            serial_number => "C02YK1TAFVCF",
            username => "fake1\@example.com",
        },
        {
            report_date_epoch => 1626877069476,
            serial_number => "C03XF8AWJG5H",
            username => "fake2\@example.com",
        }
    ]   
};

my @by_epoch =  
    sort { $a->{report_date_epoch} <=> $b->{report_date_epoch}  } 
    @{$v->{computers}};

dd $_ for @by_epoch;
```

---

I use [Data::Dump](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) to print complex data structures. (There are other good ones as well.)

Or use a core (installed) tool

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
say Dumper $_ for @by_epoch;
```

Comment: Data::Dump is the simplest of the various data dumpers.

Answer (score 0):

Sort::Key is so much cleaner than the builtin `sort`. Not much difference in this instance, but it only gets better as the task becomes more complex.

```perl
use Sort::Key qw( ikeysort );

my @by_report_date =
   ikeysort { $_->{report_date_epoch} }   # Sort them.
      @{ $a->{computers} };               # Get the elements of the array of computers.
```